# Tracing request in X-Ray for simple Java Application having AWS SDK Client

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven

I have a simple Java Application that has

- DynamoDB Client
- Table Name
- Put Item method to insert into a given table name
- aws-java-sdk dependency in POM
- aws-xray-recorder-sdk-aws-sdk-v2-instrumentor dependency in POM

When I run the application using "java -cp path class name", it executes successfully and inserts the data in the Table but traces are not showing in the Xray console.

As per my understanding "aws-xray-recorder-sdk-aws-sdk-v2-instrumentor" this dependency automatically adds the traces automatically, but somehow its not working

Comment: what is the version of aws-java-sdk used?

Comment: @BaluVyamajala 1.11.330

Answer (score 1):

`aws-xray-recorder-sdk-aws-sdk-v2-instrumentor` can be used along side as [aws-sdk-v2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html) which does automatic instrumentation of X-Ray.

For previous version of sdk, we need to include dependency [aws-xray-recorder-sdk-aws-sdk](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-xray-recorder-sdk-aws-sdk) and initialize x-ray manually.

```
AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion("us-east-1")
                .withRequestHandlers(new TracingHandler(AWSXRay.getGlobalRecorder()))
                .build();
DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);
```

Comment: do I need to add a request handler in code manually if I use SDK V2, or it will automatically trace everything?

Comment: if you use aws sdk v2 and corresponding x-ray recorder, we don't need any additional code to enable it. since you are using aws sdk v1, we need this.

Comment: I have converted my application to SDK v2 but still, I am getting an error - Failed to begin subsegment named 'DynamoDb': segment cannot be found.